# Python - Exception Handling

Tags: python, exception

Till I know, Python exception handling includes four types of keyword  (try, except, finally, Raise) + else. But I read some articles that say [throw, catch keyword](https://www.guru99.com/python-exception-handling.html#7) in Python. Really, Python has this keyword.
I read these two official documentation for Exception Handling. But they did not mention that

- [Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)
- [Built-in Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html)

Comment: That appears to be Java randomly thrown into an article on Python. I'd recommend sticking to more reliable resources than guru99 (its list of five keywords including four items is an early sign they might not be checking this stuff carefully).

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe for your reply. Randomly pick this article. But thanks for your clarification :)

Comment: The keywords associated with exception handling in Python are *try*, *except*, *finally* and *raise*. Rough equivalents between Java and Python are *catch/except* and *throw/raise* respectively

Comment: Thank You @BrutusForcus for your reply. Thanks for the clarification. And i'm missed raise

Comment: We have to he honest: nearly every statement in that article is at least questionable. It is a horrible source for learners.

Comment: Yup, I think so

Comment: Can you please clarify what this is actually asking? There isn't an explicit question here. The language specification cited should show that the third-party website is unfounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they aren't. Other languages use `throw` to give out an exception, and use `try-catch-finally` to handle one. Python uses `raise` to give out an exception, and uses `try-except-finally-else` to handle one. You can't use `try-catch-finally` or `throw` in Python.